# Trying to select something within text with a regex

Tags: php, regex

My company has a series of websites with very similar domain names based on the city. The format for these is `http://locksmithdallas.com` or `http://locksmithgarland.com`. I'd like to figure out a way to interpret Dallas and Garland out of the domain names in php. I'm a noob at regex, so I could really use some help!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (preg_match('/locksmith([^.]*)\.com/', $url, $matches)) {
    $city = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('#locksmith([^.]*)\.com#', $url, $matches)) {
    //has been found
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one's simple but you can elaborate from there:

```
http://locksmith(?<name>[a-zA-Z]+)\.com
```

That will give you a named group called "name" where you can grab the text after locksmith and before .com.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm still learning and examples are one of the best ways to do it!